# How can I optimize aggregate modificiations for concurrency access?

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

I am wondering whether it is good (and possible practice) to split one piece of data (property?) into two aggregates. Let's consider the following example:

1. There are `Debt`, `Description` and `Tag` properties.
2. There are 2 business requirements that if `Debt` value is bigger than `50.0` you cannot change `Tag` or `Description` anymore

The very first solution that comes to my mind is to create an aggregate like this along with Optimistic locking

```
public class Aggregate {
   decimal Debt { get; private set; }
   string Description { get; private set; }
   string Tag { get; private set; }
   int ConcurrencyToken { get; private set; }

   void IncreaseDebt(decimal value) {
      Debt += value;
      ConcurrencyToken++;
   }

   void ChangeDescription(string description) {
      Description = description;
      ConcurrencyToken++;
   }

   void ChangeTag(string tag) {
      Tag = tag;
      ConcurrencyToken++;
   }
```

}

Consistency of business rule is achieved, however modifying `Tag` and `Description` at the same time would cause `ConcurrentAccessException`. From business perspective user should be allowed to modify two of them at the same time.
The only solution that I see is to perform automatic retry on the client's side whenever changing `Tag` or `Description` and `ConcurrentAccessException` occurs. How to approach such problems?

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it, using an optimistic concurrency check is the right approach, but if modifying Tag and Description can be done concurrently, then you can implement the retries at the server level, not the client. So, if you have two requests coming in exactly at the same time, the behaviour from the client's point of view will be the same as if they came one after the other.

One consideration you have to make though is the experience from the user's point of view. A user makes the decision to modify the information based on the information that was presented on the screen. But when they submit the changes, someone has changed that information. For example, user A fixes a typo in the description and before submitting user B adds a full paragraph. If you just implement automatic retries (either at the client or the server) the description will be overridden. In these scenarios, you can use the Concurrency Token to detect the change (even before executing the business operation and attempting to save the aggregate) and show the user the updated information.

That said, I don't understand what you mean in the title of the question, because these two properties belong to a single aggregate and this type of solution will only work this way. In fact, that is the main point of the aggregates: maintaining data consistency based on the business rules. Data in multiple aggregates can only be eventually consistent.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I also changed the title to be more informative as you have point out.